# React Native implement JSON data on ListView

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-listview, react-native-flatlist

I'm having a problem with implementing API data in ListView. I fetched JSON using Axios.

```
export function fetchRateService() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.get(RATE_URL)
        .then(response => {
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_RATE_SERVICE,
                payload: response.data
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
  }
}
```

Reducer. I added rates data into array

```
import {
FETCH_RATE_SERVICE
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  base: '',
  date: '',
  rates: []
};
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_RATE_SERVICE:
        return { 
            ...state, 
            base: action.payload.base,
            date: action.payload.date,
            rates: [ ...state.rates, action.payload.rates ]
        };
    default:
        return state;
 }
};
```

This is the component

```
class ConturyList extends Component {

componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchRateService();
    this.createDataSource(this.props);
}

createDataSource({rates}) {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });
    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(rates);
}

renderRow(rate) {
    return <ListItem rate={rate} />
};


render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    const { CardSectionStyle, textStyle, containerStyle } = styles;
    const { visible, closeModal } = this.props;
    return (
        <Modal
            visible={visible}
            transparent={false}
            animationType="slide"
            onRequestClose={() => {this.props.closeModal()}}
        >
            <ListView
                enableEmptySections
                dataSource={this.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderRow}
            /> 
        </Modal>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { 
    rates: state.rateService.rates,
    date: state.rateService.date,
    base: state.rateService.base
  };
 }

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchRateService } )(ConturyList);
```

The problem is I can see the props data using console.log(this.props);
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKbbT.png)
I'm spending more than 3 days to figure out why this is not working. I tried using map() adding on 
`renderRow(rate) {
    return rate.map((data) => {
       return <ListItem rate={data} />
 };`
but it did not work. All the conutry code is in one object, Do I need to split the data by commas?.
Appreciate you helps. Thank you

**UPDATE**
So I'm trying to implement FlatList instead using ListView. The problem is on the JSON data. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WT9IH.png). I want to implement key which are CountryCurrencyCode(AUD, JPN, etc..) to FlatList. Since rates is an object within an object, I added rates object into an array(reducer). But `this.props.rates[0]` can't be implemented on data property of FlatList. What kind of method can I try? I can't think of anything. I could print out key using map() when rates is object and then I can't implement it on the FlatList.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend switching over to the new FlatList component over ListView. FlatList just accepts an array of data to hydrate.

Initiate this.state.datasource as an empty array

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    dataSource: [],
  }
}
```

Fetch your data and hydrate this.state.dataSource from your Redux reducer/action

```
ComponentDidMount(){
  this.props.fetchRateService();
  var myData = this.props.rates[0];
  this.setState({
    dataSource:myData
  )}
}
```

Now that your this.state.dataSource is set, we can populate FlatList

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.dataSource}
  renderItem={({item})=>this.renderRow(item)} 
/>
```

*Flat List will throw a warning about a key extractor*

Add this line below to the FlatList component. You will need to change 'item.key' to fit your own unique child. You can just keep it out for now for development.

```
keyExtractor={item => item.key}
```

You should see your data now! Keep in mind, you don't have to set the this.state.dataSource. Its just how I do it. You can plug 'this.props.rates' array directly into FlatList instead. Check out the [FlatList docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) for all the different things you can do with it. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer with the guidance. I'm new to react-native and never heard about FlatList before this answer. I'm reading the FlatList doc right now. I will try to build it using FlatList and post my result. Thank you again!!

Comment: When I tried with the guidance above `console.log(this.state.dataSource)` showed me empty array after rendered. I found out `var myData = this.props.rates` does not work(undefined) so on the FlatList data property, `data={this.props.rates}` showed me error with Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {...countrycurrencycode}. I thought the keyExtractor property taking care of keys.

Comment: Ahh, now I see whats going on. Your `this.props.rates` is an object within an object. To get the actual array, you will need to either re-write some of your reducer, or extract it by using `this.props.rates[0]`. Try `console.log(this.props.rates[0]);`. You should see just your array. For the keyExtractor, I would suggest just removing it for the time being until we get your list working.

Comment: I knew `console.log(this.props.rate[0])` will prints out all the values in the array but to implement it on data property did not work. It's null value. I don't know why. so I tried to store an object into rates on reducer. 
add method on component
`renderRow() {
        {Object.keys(this.props.rates).map((countryCode) => {
            console.log(countryCode);
            return <ListItem rate={countryCode} />
        })}
    }` it prints out the keys on the console. sounds great so far. but the problem is I can't use it on FlatList data property becuase it's not an array. hmmm....